# Can you have public and private files on the same Cloudfront distribution?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We have files serving through the Cloudfront CDN and we need to have some files to be public and some others to be private.

One option would be to have two different buckets and distributions but it is not a great solution so I was wondering if you can think of any practical solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simply denying the Cloudfront user read access to the files in the bucket that you want to keep private.

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Growse is right, if you did not set a policy for that bucket.  However, from an organizational viewpoint, it is recommended to keep private and public videos in a separate bucket.